# How to handle the case of 2 events at the same time?

Tags: c#, event-handling, observable, reactiveui

How do we combine 2 events we want to handle when occurring at the same time?

ie, Mouse Down and Value Changed?

Observable.Merge doesn't seem to do the trick?

```
var x = Observable.FromEventPattern<EventArgs>(ScrollBar, "ValueChanged");
var y = Observable.FromEventPattern<EventArgs>(ScrollBar, "PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown");

x.Merge(y)
   .Do(View => View.Property = true)
   .Subscribe();
```

Comment: Very tricky.  Wouldn't it be easier to simply check if the left mouse button is down while the ValueChanged event is happening?

Comment: You probably want to add a lock in the event so only one can execute at a time.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement

Comment: What UI platform are you coding against. I often solve this with a Where in the observable and check the mouse down state like Harvey said. Also look into the various ReactiveUI event packages. They get rid of the need to create the events using FromEventPattern